# Error: Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 0

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, string, initialization

Creating my first asp.net project.
I created a connectionstring section in my web.config file.

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="ProductivityProdConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=mssql.alliancehs.org;Initial Catalog=Productivity;Integrated Security=True;Connection Timeout=1000" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="ProductivityTestConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=mssql.alliancehs.org;Initial Catalog=Productivity;Integrated Security=True;Connection Timeout=1000" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

I then created a file called SQLControl.cs to control my data access.

I get the error "Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 0"

at the following line:

```
dbconn = new SqlConnection(connectionstring);
```

Why the error?

Full code of SQLControl.cs is below:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using global::System.Data.SqlClient;
using global::Microsoft.VisualBasic;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using global::System.IO;

namespace Productivity_ASPWeb
{
    public class SQLControl
    {
        private SqlConnection dbconn = new SqlConnection();
        private SqlCommand DBCmd;
        public SqlDataAdapter DBDA;
        public DataTable DBDT;
        public DataSet DBDS;
        public List<SqlParameter> @params = new List<SqlParameter>();
        public int recordcount;
        public string exception;

        public SQLControl()
        {
            if (GlobalVariables.logProd == 1)
            {
                GlobalVariables.strConnection = "ProductivityProdConnectionString";
            }
            else
            {
                GlobalVariables.strConnection = "ProductivityTestConnectionString";
            }
        }

        public SQLControl(string connectionstring)
        {
            if (GlobalVariables.logProd == 1)
            {
                GlobalVariables.strConnection = "ProductivityProdConnectionString";
            }
            else
            {
                GlobalVariables.strConnection = "ProductivityTestConnectionString";
            }

            connectionstring = GlobalVariables.strConnection;
            dbconn = new SqlConnection(connectionstring);
        }


        public void ExecuteQuery(string Query)
        {
            if (GlobalVariables.logProd == 1)
            {
                GlobalVariables.strConnection = "ProductivityProdConnectionString";
            }
            else
            {
                GlobalVariables.strConnection = "ProductivityTestConnectionString";
            }

            dbconn.ConnectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[GlobalVariables.strConnection].ConnectionString;
            recordcount = 0;
            exception = "";
            try
            {
                dbconn.Open();
                DBCmd = new SqlCommand(Query, dbconn);
                @params.ForEach(p => DBCmd.Parameters.Add(p));
                @params.Clear();
                DBDT = new DataTable();
                DBDS = new DataSet();
                DBDA = new SqlDataAdapter(DBCmd);
                recordcount = DBDA.Fill(DBDS);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                exception = "ExecQuery Error: " + ex.Message;
            }
            finally
            {
                if (dbconn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                {
                    dbconn.Close();
                }
            }
        }


        public void AddParam(string name, object value)
        {
            var NewParam = new SqlParameter(name, value);
            @params.Add(NewParam);
        }

        public bool HasException(bool Report = false)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(exception))
                return false;
            else
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What db are you using?

Comment: You do not need the provider name in the connection string.  You are using SQLClient in c# which uses its own provider.  You connection string should only be the attribute from the connection string and not the entire connection string.  Something like this : "Data Source=mssql.alliancehs.org;Initial Catalog=Productivity;Integrated Security=True;Connection Timeout=1000"

Comment: Using SQL Server. I removed the ProviderName portion but still got the error.

Comment: I changed this:
connectionstring = GlobalVariables.strConnection;
dbconn = new SqlConnection(connectionstring);

to:
connectionstring = "Data Source=mssql.alliancehs.org;Initial Catalog=Productivity;Integrated Security=True;Connection Timeout=1000;";
dbconn = new SqlConnection(connectionstring);

And I am no longer getting the error. I think it is reading and setting the GlobalVariables.strConnection to the name instead of the value of the connectionstring. 

I want to be able to set whether I am connecting to Prod or Test.
So I would still like to fix this issue.

Comment: The code is trying to use the name of the connection string as the connection string, instead of loading the actual connection string from the configuration file.

Comment: Also, `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand` objects are `IDisposable` - they should be wrapped in `using` blocks so that they can be disposed of as soon as they're no longer required. `SqlConnection` objects, in particular, are released back into a connection pool so that other threads can reuse them instead of establishing "expensive" new TCP connections, possibly with SSL/TLS encrypted channels, before even executing their queries.